# How to update a column in a table with data from another, unrelated tables columns data jus in order it selected?

Tags: mysql, update

There are two tables that unrelated. I want to update a field in first table with data that selected from second table in some order. There is no relations between tables, fields and data.
I have just errors from my try outs.
PS: Using MySQL.

Comment: Let`s see your try outs.

Comment: Sorry i saw late. @Rob Farley point the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a column in each table that you can update with a sequence. Then you have something to join on.

Comment: For a once-off this could be acceptable. I would be loathe to accept this as a permanent solution.

Comment: In a system that supports ROW_NUMBER() you could use that to create a pseudo-key within the query.

Comment: @RobFarley: for the select-part ROW_NUMBER can easily be substituted (@rownr:=@rownr+1), but to UPDATE a certain row I know no way.

Comment: Well... In SQL Server and most others, you'd be able to do updates based on joins that leverage row_number().